# akka http: Server Binding not behaving as expected

Tags: akka-http

I have following code:

```
val serverSource = Http().bind("localhost", 8080)
val connectionSink = Sink.foreach[IncomingConnection] {
    connection => println(s"Accepted incoming connection from ${connection.remoteAddress}")
  }
val serverBindingFuture = serverSource.to(connectionSink).run()
serverBindingFuture.onComplete {
    case Success(binding) => {
      println("Server binding successful")
      binding.terminate(10 seconds)
    }
    case Failure(ex) => println(s"Server binding failed $ex")
}
```

As the snippet tells, I am terminating the server binding after 10 seconds. So I expect that if I send the request before this period expires, I should get message 'Accepted incoming connection from...' printed.

But I observe that I always get 'This site can’t be reached', and message is never printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the snippet tells, I am terminating the server binding after 10 seconds. So I expect that if I send the request before this period expires, I should get message 'Accepted incoming connection from...' printed.

You've misunderstood the semantics of `terminate`. The duration argument is a *hard* deadline for shutdown, not an indication that the server will continue accepting requests until then.

Here's a tweak to your code to demonstrate this.

- print `Server binding successful` as soon as the server is up and wait 10 seconds before calling `terminate`
- print `Starting shutdown` right before calling `terminate` and print `Finished shutdown` as soon as the `terminate` completes

You should see:

- `curl 'http://localhost:8080/api` triggers the `println` until `Starting shutdown` appears
- the delay between `Starting shutdown` and `Finished shutdown` is likely to be quite short (much shorter that 10 seconds)

```scala
val serverSource = Http().bind("localhost", 8080)
val connectionSink = Sink.foreach[IncomingConnection] {
  connection => println(s"Accepted incoming connection from ${connection.remoteAddress}")
}
val serverBindingFuture = serverSource.to(connectionSink).run()
serverBindingFuture.onComplete {
  case Success(binding) => {
    println("Server binding successful")
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 seconds) {
      println("Starting shutdown")
      binding.terminate(10 seconds).onComplete { termOutcome =>
        println(s"Finished shutdown $termOutcome")
      }
    }
  }
  case Failure(ex) => println(s"Server binding failed $ex")
}
```